# Flash CS 5.5 - Icon Image are smoothed with HIGH quality on swf

Tags: image, actionscript-3, flash

This is very strange.
I would like to show in my swf movie all the icons (jpg/png) I've imported as they are.
I've set the JPG quality 100%, I've tried the PNG settings without quality lost, I've unchecked the "Allow smooth" setting.

But as soon as the movie have quality=high all the icons are smoothed/breaked and do not looks like the original ones ( http://www.emagi.it/icon/icon_high.html ).

Instead, setting quality=low let show the icons as they are!
( http://www.emagi.it/icon/icon_low.html ).

Of course, I need the movie to be quality=high, since there will be some other stuff on it!
So, setting the quality=low is not the solution!

Thank you very much.

Comment: They are same in both the movies buddy

Comment: @pranavhosangadi, if you look very carefully, you'll see that they are not the same. In the first one, the icons are smoothed, in the second they are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check two things:

1. Make sure the icons' coordinates are not floating point numbers. i.e. they should be exactly "10", not "10.2".
2. Make sure the instances on the stage have the exact same dimensions as the icons in the library. i.e. if they resolution is 16x16, make sure they are not 16.1x15.8 on stage.

With quality=low Flash is going to round the coordinates to the nearest pixel, which is why the icons look right in this mode.

Comment: the problem was generated by the floating point x,y! Using a int number for the el.x, el.y solved out the problem. Thank you for this trick ;-)